# tcp_autocorking and tcp_abc file not found in linux kernel 3.13

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel, ipv4

I am trying to change

- tcp_autocorking
- tcp_abc

  values in linux. I have manually tried to change the value in file and also use **sysctl** but nothing works, as the corresponding files for tcp_autocorking and tcp_abc in `proc/sys/net/ipv4/` does not exist. I am using ***Ubuntu 14 with 3.13 kernel***. Thanks!

Comment: In kernel 4.*, tcp_autocorking does exist in proc/sys/net/ipv4/ but tcp_abc (appropriate byte counting) is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

tcp_abc was removed [in this commit](https://es.osdn.net/projects/android-x86/scm/git/kernel/commits/ca2eb5679f8ddffff60156af42595df44a315ef0), which was merged in 3.9.

Comment: I screwed the [link](https://es.osdn.net/projects/android-x86/scm/git/kernel/commits/ca2eb5679f8ddffff60156af42595df44a315ef0) (shame on me, this is markdown)

Comment: Fixed it for you!